# How to convert unkown character set into utf8?

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8-decode

I have the string Mühle saved as MÃÂ¼hle in a utf8 database. I want it to be in UTF8 so it will show properly on my webpage which also uses utf8.

I think the string was not converted into utf8 befor writing it into the database and now it won't show properly on my web page.

I tried selecting this string from my mysql database and converting it into utf8, but it didn't work. I also tried decoding it multiple times, but also that didn't work. See the code I used for that below:

```
$string = MÃÂ¼hle;
$string=utf8_encode($string);
echo $string;
```

and

```
$string = MÃÂ¼hle;
$string=utf8_decode($string);
$string=utf8_encode($string);
echo $string;
```

The output of the above code was the same as the input in both cases, not changing anything about the string.

What can I do to convert this string in such a way that I can update it in my mysql database and when selecting it the next time it will show properly as Mühle?

Comment: Are you sure the original input is correct? Because when you convert 'Mühle' from latin1 to utf8, the result is 'MÃ¼hle'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is *double-encoded* UTF-8 - that is, UTF-8 that was interpreted as Latin-1 and then re-encoded to UTF-8.

This can happen when you mess up your character encodings - e.g. when you send UTF-8 data while your MySQL is expecting the connection to use Latin-1. To fix this, you will need to call [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset) (or the equivalent function for your database API) as soon as you create the connection, or modify the MySQL configuration to use UTF-8 connections by default.

Furthermore, you will need to fix your data - this is done using utf8_decode an appropriate number of times. If "MÃÂ¼hle" is the exact bytes returned by your database *with a UTF-8 connection*, you need to read that string, send it through utf8_decode, and then update that row (still using a UTF-8 connection).

Please note that when you select a row in MySQL, *it gets converted from the table character set to the connection character set* before getting sent back to the client. So, if you're seeing "MÃÂ¼hle" on your screen, MySQL is using a UTF-8 connection, *and* you're displaying the string as UTF-8, you need to call utf8_decode *twice* in order to fix it, because this means the string is actually triple-encoded - twice in the database text, and once for the display. **Double-check everything**, preferably using a well-developed MySQL client like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) - until it is displayed properly there, *your data is still encoded incorrectly*.

If this is only an issue with a few rows, manual fixing is okay; if it's a general problem with your database, you might prefer to dump an SQL script, convert *that* file, and use it to replace your old data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function.  It'll convert the string back to UTF-8.

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string)
{
$string = htmlentities($string);
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
$string = htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false)));

$s = array(
    chr(145) => "'",
    chr(146) => "'",
    chr(147) => '"',
    chr(148) => '"',
    chr(151) => '-',
    's&#169;' => '©',
    '&#174;' => '®',
    '&#153;' => '™', //&trade;
    'â€œ' => '"', // left side double smart quote
    'â€' => '"', // right side double smart quote
    'â€˜' => "'", // left side single smart quote
    'â€™' => "'", // right side single smart quote
    'â€¦' => '...', // elipsis
    'â€”' => '-', // em dash
    'â€“' => '-', // en dash
);

return strtr($string, $s);
}
```